# Add a custom property to an existing DOM event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it ok to add a custom property to an existing DOM event? I would like to "mark" click events in a leaf element (say, a `<span>`) and catch the event (after bubbling) in an ancestor (say, `<body>`) and take a decision based on that mark.

Comment: You can use the built-in mechanism of [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

Comment: Why is that information not available when the ancestor deals with the bubbled event? You do have the `target` property...

Comment: @ChrisG `dataset` is for element objects, not event objects

Comment: @trincot indeed I could look at the clicked element but there can be many such elements and they would all need to be marked. I was just curios if a dom element also supports some `dataset` or `detail` property so that it can be extended on the fly.

Comment: I was talking about the leaf element's dataset, not the event's. Just set some flag variable and check it in the body's event handler, then reset it. This sounds like an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your question needs more concrete information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sure you can add new properties to an event.

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a way to uniquely identify a specific event so you can de-dupe or count unique events or whatever.

For instance if you have one event handler handling some events on different elements and you want to make sure you handle each event only once.  If an event bubbles you might handle the same event on multiple elements.  Some events might bubble, some might not (e.g. because another handler called `Event.stopPropogation()` lower in the dom tree.  Maybe you don't have that much control over where you attach your event handlers and have to rely on bubbling in some cases.

### Example...

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var parentEl = document.querySelector('#parent'),
    childEl = document.querySelector('#child');

child.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var rand = ''+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
    console.log('child', rand);
    e.custField = rand;
});
parent.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('parent', e);
});
child.click();
```

Downside of this is that you are polluting someone else's objects that might be handled by code that isn't your own.  Not usually a great idea.

## Alternatively

### 1) Use `Event.timeStamp`

Your event handler can keep a cache of `Event.timeStamp` and use that to de-dupe handled events.

```js
var eventHandler = (function () {
    var eventTimeStampCache = {};

    return function (evt) {
        if (evt.timeStamp in eventTimeStampCache) {
            console.log('Ignore this event.', evt);
            return;
        }
        eventTimeStampCache[evt.timeStamp] = true;
        console.log('Handle this event.', evt);
    };
})();

child.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
parent.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
child.click();
```

### 2) Use CustomEvent

If you are firing the events in the first place, use a CustomEvent that is all your own and feel free to make custom APIs and add event listeners that listen for your custom event.

I'd suggest firing a CustomEvent in response to the standard event except you have the same problem of knowing if this has been done already or not.

Comment: Event.timeStamp sounds good, thanks! The only thing to be careful about is that some events have the same timestamp, eg mouseup and click.

Comment: fair point.  of course you could adapt the "event handled cache" approach to use both event type and timestamp as the cache key or do sub-level caching based on event type where you then cache the timestamps.  Just depends on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `dataset` item to the element called "data-xxx"

```html
<span id="id" data-myvar="myvalue"></span>
```

And then later on

```js
console.log( document.getElementbyID('id').dataset.myvar ) // myvalue
```

Comment: the question is about adding a custom property to a DOM Event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), not an element